# Images have disappeared

Tags: channel-entries

Using ExpressionEngine v2.9.2 - Build Date: 20141004 - © Copyright 2003 - 2016 EllisLab, Inc.

All images have disappeared from our website: www.wordworks.jp I am guessing that a broken link to the Expression Engine database is to blame.

If you know how to fix this, please tell me how. Am willing to pay to get this sorted out ASAP.

Comment: Have you asked your developers? http://www.boyink.com

Answer (score 1):

All your images point to http://wordworks.**ehclients.com/images/** but there is a server error (Server not found). I suppose that is the problem.

Answer (score 0):

A field that might come in handy is "URL of Upload Directory" in the area:

Content > Files > File Upload Preferences > (your image folder)

I'd also check on "Server Path to Upload Directory". This begins with a slash, e.g., "/www/website/images/uploads"